# Difference between modular curves $X_0(N)$ and $X_1(N)$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding how these 2 curves differ, i.e. how the points on these curves differ.

As I understand, for an algebraic number field $K$, a point on $X_1(N)(K)$ parameterizes a pair $(E,P)$, where $E$ is an elliptic curve with coefficients over $K$ and $P$ is a $K-$rational point on $E$ of order $N$. Furthermore, a point on $X_0(N)(K)$ parameterizes a pair $(E,C)$, where $E$ is an elliptic curve with coefficients over $K$ and $C$ is a cyclic subgroup of order $N$.

So if we have $(E,P)\in X_1(N)(K)$, then $(E,\langle P\rangle )$ is a point on $X_1(N)(K).$ Conversely, if we have $(E,C)\in X_0(N)(K)$ and $P$ is a generator of $C$, then $(E,P)\in X_1(N)(K)$.

How are these curves different? Am I missing something? Does maybe $P$ from $(E,P)\in X_1(N)(K)$ have to be $K-$rational and $C$ from $(E,C)\in X_0(N)(K)$ only has to be $Gal(\overline{K}/K)-$invariant?

Comment: When you are given $C$, you choose(!) a generator $P$, but usually there will be more than one, so $P$ is not unique.

Comment: @Notone Is that the only difference?

Comment: @Nom yes.In fact $X_1(N)$ is a covering space for $X_0(N)$ with $\Phi(N)$ layer(number of generators) as you can also see from their construction as quotients of upper half-plane

Comment: @Nom If you work over $\mathbb{C}$, then yes. They will differ by an action of $(\mathbb{Z}/N)^x$. In general it depends on what you understand as $X_0(N)$ but it will be a $(\mathbb{Z}/N)^x$-torsor